# Running sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats in parallel

Tags: sql-server, performance, index, sql-server-2014

I am trying to get fragmentation information on a few tables which are over 500 GB and I am using the `...DETAILED` option of `sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats`.  I am doing this on a restore copy of the production database on our pre-Prod server so I don't care about hurting any performance on the server.

I ran it and it looks like it is running in serial and it is taking forever. Is there a way to run `dm_db_index_physical_stats()` in parallel? Or is any other setting interfering with it?

I guess `DBCC TRACEON (8649)` and `OPTION(USE HINT('ENABLE_PARALLEL_PLAN_PREFERENCE'))` are not available in SQL Server 2014.

Also tried `DBCC SETCPUWEIGHT(1000);` from Paul White's blog [here](https://www.sql.kiwi/2011/12/forcing-a-parallel-query-execution-plan.html). The blog mentions about parallelism inhibitor and one of which is system tables. Is `dm_db_index_physical_stats()` considered a system table?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats
```

is a system table valued function.

Internally this will perform an openrowset call to an internal `INDEXANALYSIS` system data source.

```
create function [sys].[dm_db_index_physical_stats]
(
    @DatabaseId         SMALLINT        = 0,
    @ObjectId           INT             = 0,
    @IndexId            INT             = -1,
    @PartitionNumber    INT             = 0,
    @Mode               nvarchar(20)    = NULL
)
returns table
as
    return select *
        from OpenRowset
        (   TABLE
            INDEXANALYSIS,
            @DatabaseId,
            @ObjectId,
            @IndexId,
            @PartitionNumber,
            @Mode
        )
GO
```

More info on these internal data sources [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/195099/internally-how-does-openrowsettable-work).

You can find the same `INDEXANALYSIS` TVF call in the execution plan:

[image]

And you can also see that it is a multi statement table valued function.

[image]

So the query will not be able to use parallelism due to reason **#1**: system table access

> The list changes from version to version, but for example these things
> make the whole plan serial on SQL Server 2012:
>
> - ...
> - System table access (e.g. reading from sys.tables)

The TVF call will also be serial due to reason **#2**: Multi statement TVF

> These query features are examples that require a serial zone in the
>
> - ...
> - Multi-statement T-SQL table-valued functions

[Source](https://www.sql.kiwi/2011/12/forcing-a-parallel-query-execution-plan.html)